# Small values and Negative nonlinear susceptibility of a degenerate parametric amplifier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, optical-materials

The quantum Hamiltonian of a degenerative parametric amplifier (DPA) is given by (taking $\hbar=1$
$$
\hat{H}=\omega\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+2\omega\hat{b}^{\dagger}\hat{b}+\kappa\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}\hat{b}+\hat{a}^{2}\hat{b}^{\dagger }\right),
$$
where $\hat{a} \ (\hat{a}^{\dagger})$ and $\hat{b} \ (\hat{b}^{\dagger})$ are the annihilation (creation) operators for the signal and pump modes, respectively, and $\kappa$ is the coupling constant which is proportional to the nonlinear second-order susceptibility $\chi^{(2)}$.

The parametric approximation can be made if we consider a strong intensity in the pumping field, in such a way that the quantum operators can be treated classically so that $\hat{b}\rightarrow \beta_0$ and $\hat{b}^{\dagger}\rightarrow \beta_0^*$, where (*) indicates the conjugate complex, and considering a static pump field. In this form, the Hamiltonian is
$$
\hat{H}_{DPA}=\omega\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+\kappa\left(\beta_0\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}+\beta_0^{*} \hat{a}^{2}\right).
$$

Regarding this Hamiltonian, two questions arise for me:

1. according to https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.52.815: 
   "In fact, the classical pump approximation
   requires an additional, more subtle assumption, namely,
   that the nonlinear susceptibility of the medium $\chi^{(2)}$
   (or
   the coupling constant $\kappa$) be small". The question is which values of $\kappa$  can be considered "small"?
2. Could $\kappa$ take negative values and what does mean this physical process?